# Application Gateway Ingress Controller I am not able to access the application throgh Ingress controller but was able to access throgh LB External IP

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have created Ingress Controller for my deployment and I am able to access for some time and when i tried the same sometime later i was not able to access the application. But, I was able to access the application with LoadBalancer External IP at the same time. Please can someone help here.
Here is my deployment:

````
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: lable
  name: label
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: label
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: label
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <Image Name>
        name: label
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: "UAT"
        - name: EnvironmentName
          value: "UAT"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mst-storage
          mountPath: /home/appuser/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys
      volumes:
      - name: mst-storage
        emptyDir: {}
status: {}


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: label
spec:
  selector:
    app: label
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
  
 
---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: label
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http: 
      paths:
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          service:
            name: label
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          service:
            name: label
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: label
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
      ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you still facing this issue? You can always check application gateway ingress controller logs which constantly monitors the changes in the AKS PODS and pass that information to Application Gateway so that both components are in sync. If there are any issues those logs will clearly show the error information.

Example Command:

kubectl logs ingress-appgw-deployment-* -n kube-system

Also in the above deployment YAML file , can you kindly check the below section under metadata->labels. It was mentioned as  app: lable (There is a spell mistake ?)

kind: Deployment

metadata:

creationTimestamp: null

labels:

```
app: lable
```

Compare that with Service YAML file (Spec -> Selector -> app: label )

spec:

selector:

```
app: label
```